# Netlify error: "You have a malformed package.json in your folder."

Tags: reactjs, package.json, netlify

i'm trying to deploy react app from github to netlify, but it's giving me "You have a malformed package.json in your folder. This will most likely lead to a broken build when attempting to install your npm dependencies."
i've deleted and reinstalled node modules, package-lock.json, yet still not working [Netlify error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp6UA.png)
[package json file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdIQ5.png)

Comment: show your package.json

Comment: i've added the package json file image so you can see

Comment: try to use this. http://ww7.package-json-validator.com/ and validate your package.json.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your package.json and package-lock.json are incompatible.
Remove package-lock, remove node_modules, install deps again with `npm i` command and commit the change and push everything to Netlify.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, it's a browser issue, I was using chrome, and when I used edge browser, it didn't show that error anymore, I'll have to update chrome.